# changing css atribute with jquery clicking on a link and back. could anyone help me?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm very new at using jquery, I would apreciate greatly if someone could help me with this.

I have some elements on my web with a class:

```
.hidden {display:none}
```

Then I made a link that looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:test()">Test</a>
```

and the script that so far I have manage to write is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    function test() {                   
        $(".hidden").css({ display: "inherit" });
    };
</script>
```

So far it works as expected but... how can I make that if I click again on the link, display:none again?

Ty very much in advance and excuse my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/JsGd4/

```
<a href="javascript:test()">Test</a>

<div class="hidden">assaas</div>
<script>
    function test() {
        $('.hidden').toggle();
    };
</script>

.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Ty very much. so easy (now that I see it). I won't forget it

Answer (score 3):

```
function test() {  
    var hide=$('.hidden').css('display');
    var class=(hide=='none') ? "inherit" : "none";  
    $(".hidden").css({ display: class });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in jQuery function to do this: [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
function test(){
    $('.hidden').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example: DIV MENU with CLASS & ID

```js
$('#panel').click( function() { 
 if ($("div.menu").css("display") == "none") { 
  $("div.menu").css("display","inline-table"); 
 } else {
  $("div.menu").css("display","none"); 
 }
});
```

```css
.menu ul li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="panel">==SHOW/HIDDEN==</a><br>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>TEST 1</li>
    <li>TEST 2</li>
    <li>TEST 3</li>
    <li>TEST 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well,... Thanks for the answer even if it was asked close to 2 years ago. It has helped me to remember how little I knew and how much I have improved over all this time which feels nice. :)